# Page not found error in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am getting the following error

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Action "index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()``

Stack trace: 0 /var/www/square/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(518): Zend_Controller_Action->__call('indexAction', Array) 
1 /var/www/square/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
2 /var/www/square/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Htt‌​p), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) 
3 /var/www/square/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
4 /var/www/square/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() 
5 /var/www/square/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run() 
6 {main} Request Parameters: array ( 'module' => 'catalog', 'controller' => 'item', 'action' => 'index', )
```

The URL I'm trying to use is :

```
/square/public/catalog/item/
```

Comment: What is your controller that should be run ? catalog ?

Comment: no ,its ItemController

Comment: So, in your itemController, do you have a public function indexAction ?

Comment: no , i donot have it , what code should i add there ?

Comment: When you do not supply an action in the URL (`.../controller/action` so in your case `.../item/action`) the default action is `index` (if i'm not wrong). So the framework is searching for an action with the name index. add a `public function indexAction()` which made some process and redirect to the index view and that should be fine.

Comment: @user1073122 Now , after adding IndexAction , i am getting this error 
script 'item/index.phtml' not found in path (/var/www/square/application/modules/catalog/views/scripts/)

Comment: Yes. As I said, when an action is finished, the framework will try to print the corresponding view (because the role of the action is to do some stuff with the model layer, and then prepare data that will be shown to the view). So you should have a view corresponding to your action. Create an index.phtml file in /views/scripts/ and that should be fine.

Comment: yes , i added an action here /var/www/square/application/modules/catalog/view/scripts/item/index.phtml , but it's still giving the same error like :
Message: script 'item/index.phtml' not found in path (/var/www/square/application/modules/catalog/views/scripts/)

Answer (score 1):

In you code the controller you specified is `ItemController` and when you tyry to run the program the action which executes is the indexAction.First check whether you have written the `indexAction` in your controller.If its not in your controller specify the index action..I guess thats the problem.. And try to post your code also.

Comment: yeah i added  indexAction and the index.phtml also, but i am still getting the error like  :: Message: script 'item/index.phtml' not found in path (/var/www/square/application/modules/catalog/views/scripts/).Do you want to see the code of ItemController

Comment: @user1073122  Please tell me what code should be written in the indexAction to make the following code run:

Comment: <?php
class Catalog_ItemController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
public function init()
{
$this->view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
}
public function indexAction()
{

}
}
}

 function displayAction()
{
// set filters and validators for GET input
$filters = array(
'id' => array( 'StripTags', 'StringTrim')
);
$validators = array(
'id' => array('NotEmpty', 'Int')
);
// test if input is valid
// retrieve requested record
// attach to view
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);
$input->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());
if ($input->isValid()) {
$this->db = new PDO('mysql:

Comment: $this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=square;host=localhost', 'root',
'');
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql=$db->query('SELECT Country,Grade,Type FROM Item where RecordID=?');
$stmt=new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysql($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('goofy','FIXED'));
$result = $q->fetchArray();
return $this->db->lastInsertId();
}
if (count($result) == 1) {
$this->view->item = $result[0];
} 
}
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Besides things, which was already said, I see you are using modules. Did you enable this feature in ZF configuration (or directly somewhere in source, e.g. Boostrap) ?

In application.ini, you should have something like this :

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

Also module (I think) must contains it's own Boostrap class (extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap)